# Why can't I import my photoshop SVG in sketch

Tags: adobe-photoshop, svg, sketch-app, import

In sketch, I choose edit->insert image, then search for the SVG...It is listed but greyed-out and non-selectable. I can import any other valid image format.

Everywhere I read about importing in sketch, it says that SVG is a valid format and no one else seems to have trouble importing these.

Answer (score 1):

### **Bad News:**

Going through the `Edit > Insert Image` menu won't work. It's meant for rasterized files (e.g., `.JPEG`, `.PNG`, `.BMP`, etc.)

---

### **Good News:**

Granted that the file is a legitimate `.svg`, you can use it in Sketch two different ways:

1. Drag the file from your Finder and drop it into your `.sketch` file.
2. Right click the `.svg` file in Finder, and select `Open With > Sketch`. It will create a new `.sketch` document with just the `.svg` in it.

Answer (score 0):

SVG is a coded file format (XML-based) and Sketch could be coding something in a way Illustrator doesn't like.

You could try using an SVG Optimizer like [SVGOMG - SVGO's Missing GUI](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/) to see if it can clean up the code so Illustrator doesn't choke on it.

I just tried it on an SVG that Illustrator had problems importing and it didn't crash. It still gave an error and then looked wrong but after running the SVG through that SVGOMG website, it imported without error and looked correct.

Answer (score -1):

Sketch is a vector-based program. SVG files are intended to be vectors. If you've created something in photoshop and just saved it as an SVG file, chances are it's a raster file (pixel-based).

Sketch does import image formats (jpg, png, gif, etc.), so if you're trying to import an image to your design that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I created the image as a vector. I took a png, made a path out of it, then saved that path as a custom shape. Then I made a new photoshop document, and created a shape using that custom shape. Then I exported it as an SVG. See anything wrong with my workflow?

Comment: My understanding is that no matter what, Photoshop can't export vectors. I could be wrong. If you open it in Illustrator is it an editable vector?